# Trying to get Ubuntu mate into recovery mode

Tags: password, data-recovery

Ubuntu Mate on Raspberry pi 3+ and lost the password.  Tried going to Recovery mode by restarting and pressing either by holding shift key or esc or space bar.  But neither of them put it into Recovery mode.  I need to reset the lost password.  Maybe there is another way? Thanks, Mike

Comment: Have you considered taking the SD card out of your RPi 3 and connecting it to a computer while in either a Linux OS or booted to a Linux Live USB?  From there you can chroot into the system disk and then modify things and then return the SD card to the RPi and then it should be 'good as new' then.